# Pokemon Login keeps going back to enter age screen

Tags: pokemon-go

I have cleared my Pokemon App cache and cleared all data, but it still keeps going back to the input screen.

I have also deleted Pokemon Go several times and after inputting the age, it will allow you to choose a player account but after it will not allow access to the game and return to the age input screen.

Could you please advise?

Comment: Are you using a Google, Facebook, or TPC account to login?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android q beta, Pokemon go is not optimized for it and many people are running into this problem. None of Niantic's games work with Q including Ingress and the new Harry Potter game.